# How do I scroll a child div within a parent div that doesn't scroll?

Tags: scroll

How do I scroll a child div within a fixed parent does not scroll? I've tried approved solutions on stack overflow but they are not working.  What's wrong with my code below?  Thanks:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
   <style type="text/css">
   #parent{
      height: 100px;
      width: 300px;
      overflow: hidden;
      border: 1px solid gray;
   }
    
   #child{
      height: 200px;
      width: 300px;
      border: 1px solid red;
      overflow: auto;
   }
    
   </style>
        
</head>

<body>
   <div id="parent">
      <div id="child">
      this is what I want to scroll, this is what I want to scroll,
      this is what I want to scroll, this is what I want to scroll,
      this is what I want to scroll, this is what I want to scroll,
      this is what I want to scroll, this is what I want to scroll,
      this is what I want to scroll, this is what I want to scroll,
      this is what I want to scroll, this is what I want to scroll,
      </div>
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you are wanting, do you want the child div to sit inside the parent div, and only be able to scroll information inside the child div? I copied your code and made a couple changes on how it looks. Run the code snippet and let me know if this what you meant?

```css
#parent {
  height: 100px;
  width: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  padding: 1rem;
}

#child {
  height: 100px;
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">  
  <div id="child">
    <p>This is what I want to scroll, This is what I want to scroll,</p>
    <p>This is what I want to scroll, This is what I want to scroll,</p>
    <p>This is what I want to scroll, This is what I want to scroll,</p>
    <p>This is what I want to scroll, This is what I want to scroll,</p>
    <p>This is what I want to scroll, This is what I want to scroll,</p>
    <p>This is what I want to scroll, This is what I want to scroll,</p>
    <p>This is what I want to scroll, This is what I want to scroll,</p>
    <p>This is what I want to scroll, This is what I want to scroll,</p>
    <p>This is what I want to scroll, This is what I want to scroll,</p>
    <p>This is what I want to scroll, This is what I want to scroll,</p>
    <p>This is what I want to scroll, This is what I want to scroll,</p>
    <p>This is what I want to scroll, This is what I want to scroll,</p>
    <p>This is what I want to scroll, This is what I want to scroll,</p>
    <p>This is what I want to scroll, This is what I want to scroll,</p>
    <p>This is what I want to scroll, This is what I want to scroll,</p>
    <p>This is what I want to scroll, This is what I want to scroll,</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I just needed more content in the child div in order for the scroll to activate.  This is issue is resolved.